# Tableofcontents does not workt with \nocite

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, errors, citing, overleaf

I am writing my BA Thesis and at the end of my paper i wanted to cite all papers (lots of problems with `\cite{}` etc. so did not use it). Now i have to make a reference list.

I did not use any code in the text for citations.

Now i need my reference section. I tried it with `\nocite{*}`. It worked but there are two problems now:

1. My tableofcontent does not appear when I use `\nocite{*}`. Without * it appears but then i have no reference list.
2. The title of the reference list should be highlighted / bold and as well appear later in the table of contents.

Help is appreciated:)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,floatsintext,donotrepeattitle,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{hyperref} %For referencing tables and figures
\usepackage{subcaption} %allows for subfigures to align them next to each other
\usepackage{pdfpages} %This is to insert the front page from the word template

\beging{document}
\section{Abstract}
\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{Introduction}
\section{Theory}
\subsection{Effects}
\section{Discussion}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{BA}
```

Comment: well probably you should have solved the problems with \cite directly instead of going the lazy way and not using the command. In any case: you will have to provide a complete example with the bib-file and also the log and the blg-file. And don't use utf8x, it is not compatible with many things.

Comment: I ran your MWE which did produce a ToC. However it reported an undefined control sequence `\@shorttitle`. I ma using `texlive 2020`.